# How long would take for other galaxies to be unobservable due to Cosmic Expansion?

Tags: space-expansion, universe, galaxies

I heard that if Universal Expansion continues at some point galaxies will be so separated that a future civilization would have no way to know there are other galaxies, for them the Galaxy they live in is alone in the universe. (I'm planning to write a sci-fi story about it). Thus more or less in what time frame would that expansion would cause that effect? Thank you in advance.